# How to get XML node names while Converting an XML to CSV?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, csv

Here is the code i have used to convert it to csv.which works fine.

```
function xml2array($file) {
$string = file_get_contents($file);
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $string, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($parser);    
$ary=array();
$i=-1;
foreach ($vals as $r){
    if($r['level'] == 1)continue;
    if($r['level'] == 2 && $r['type'] == "open"){
        ++$i;
        continue;
        }
    $ary[$i][$r['tag']] = @$r['value'];
}
return $ary;
}
$array=xml2array('inventory.xml');
$outstream = fopen('inventory.csv','w');
$header=false;
foreach($array as $k=>$details){
if(!$header){
    fputcsv($outstream,$details);
    $header=true;
}
fputcsv($outstream,$details);
}
fclose($outstream);
```

**Problem:** i am getting proper data in the csv but not getting XML headers (node names) in my generated csv.What is missing?Help me

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow isn't really a repair station for copy & pasted code. Askers are expected to show *some* effort of their own.

Comment: @pekka well thats my effort sir.What i need is need to know where i am wrong in terms to retrieve header values.Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the array_keys(), although it should be noted that for it to work this way all items in the xml must have the exact same structure and no nested childnodes I believe. If so, this will work:

```
function xml2array($file) {
$string = file_get_contents($file);
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $string, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($parser);    
$ary=array();
$i=-1;
foreach ($vals as $r){
    if($r['level'] == 1)continue;
    if($r['level'] == 2 && $r['type'] == "open"){
        ++$i;
        continue;
        }
    $ary[$i][$r['tag']] = @$r['value'];
}
return $ary;
}

$array=xml2array('inventory.xml');
$outstream = fopen('inventory.csv','w');
//output the names of the first array item's keys
fputcsv($outstream, array_keys($array[0]));
foreach($array as $k=>$details){
    fputcsv($outstream,$details);
}
fclose($outstream);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$header){
    fputcsv($outstream,$details);
    $header=true;
}
fputcsv($outstream,$details);
```

The `fputcsv` in the if-branch does exactly the same as the unconditional one, so it just duplicates the first row. see http://docs.php.net/array_keys

Comment: yup, its doing the same.i am modifying it.thanx for reponse